# BufferedImage from RGB byte[] array

Tags: java

I have a byte[] array with RGB values. I would like to create BufferedImage without setting the pixels one by one, as the image can be big. I've found the following snippet:

```
        byte[] frame = ...;
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        img.setData(Raster.createRaster(img.getSampleModel(), new DataBufferByte(frame, frame.length), new Point() ) );
```

Which does work nice, but there is a small issue ;-) `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` is expecting bytes in reverse order.

So the questions are:

1. Is it possible to load my array somehow without actually creating a new byte array with expected ordering?
2. If its not possible, is there any better way than for loop to copy data from RGB format to BGR?

Comment: Why can’t you create a second array or reassign an edited array to `frame`?

Comment: Poking around at other options to construct your classes, I found `TYPE_INT_RGB`. Perhaps converting the byte array to an int array could work?

Comment: What's wrong with option 2? (if you change the order in-place in your existing byte array) Your computer won't complain that it's tedious - that is the type of work that computers are good at.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt just feels like copying 75000000 items (given 5000x5000 image) just to then load them to bufferedimage is not the greatest solution. I will do it if I need to but I would prefer to avoid that

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt actually it doesn't make sense at all in this case, much better to just call setRGB on buffered image instance if I have to iterate over the byte array

Comment: You should look at the implementation of `BufferedImage.setData` as it copies the data from the raster that you pass in line by line. `BufferedImage.getRaster().setDataElements` looks to be the method that you should be using if you are concerned about performance much. (And you should only be if you perform this operation frequently, liking multiple times per second)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt yeah if I wouldnt do that a lot I wouldnt bother. setData maybe does the same thing but its faster than manual loop, I dont know why. setDataElements is expecting different format so its again the same issue. I will go for loop solution for now as at least it works, will come back to this later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
BufferedImage img = create3ByteRGBImage(int width, int height, new int[] {8, 8, 8},
                                     new int[] {0, 1, 2});    

private BufferedImage create3ByteRGBImage(width, height, int[] nBits, int[] bOffs) {
            ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);
            ColorModel colorModel =
                new ComponentColorModel(cs, nBits,
                                        false, false,
                                        Transparency.OPAQUE,
                                        DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
            WritableRaster raster =
                Raster.createInterleavedRaster(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE,
                                               width, height,
                                               width*3, 3,
                                               bOffs, null);
            return new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, false, null);
        }
```

Comment: Great ;) so I edited the answer and left only the first suggestion as it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer works but it can be simplified to be more readable:

```
ColorSpace colorSpace = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);

ColorModel model = new ComponentColorModel(
    colorSpace, 
    false,
    true, 
    Transparency.OPAQUE, 
    DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE
);

WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(
    DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, 
    width, 
    height, 
    3, 
    null
);

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(model, raster, true, null);
```